# Optimizing query with multiple CASEs with Count depending on column content

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2014

I have a part of a query which I am trying to optimize. My tables have a lot of info and it would be good for us to know if we could optimize it a little bit.

This part is the one that is taking longer:

```
CASE 
        WHEN {SPS_FACTURAS}.[TipoFactura] = 'F' 
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IsPurged] = 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NumRec)
                                                   FROM {SPS_LINFARMA} linfarma
                                                  WHERE linfarma.[IdCodFact] = {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IdCodFact])
        WHEN {SPS_FACTURAS}.[TipoFactura] = 'F' 
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IsPurged] = 1 THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NumRec)
                                                   FROM {SPS_HISTLINFARMA} histfarm
                                                  WHERE histfarm.[IdCodFact] = {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IdCodFact])
        WHEN {SPS_FACTURAS}.[TipoFactura] = 'C' 
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[NomUsrIns] <> 'WS_Faturacao'
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IsPurged] = 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NUMFICH)
                                                   FROM {SPS_LINFACT2} linha
                                                  WHERE linha.[IdCodFact] = {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IdCodFact])
        WHEN {SPS_FACTURAS}.[TipoFactura] = 'C' 
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[NomUsrIns] <> 'WS_Faturacao'
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IsPurged] = 1 THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NUMFICH)
                                                   FROM {SPS_HISTLINFACT} histlin
                                                  WHERE histlin.[IdCodFact] = {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IdCodFact])
        WHEN {SPS_FACTURAS}.[TipoFactura] = 'C' 
         AND {SPS_FACTURAS}.[NomUsrIns] = 'WS_Faturacao' 
                                           THEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NUMFICH)
                                                   FROM {SPS_LINFACTWS} linWS
                                                  WHERE linWS.[IdCodFact] = {SPS_FACTURAS}.[IdCodFact])
        END
```

Is there a way I can optimize it?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Vincent Colpa

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Pretty sparse on details here with only a portion of your query. But I would suggest creating variables to hold the results of each of these queries. This looks like you may be running the same exact subquery over and over. Without the whole query and the execution plan we are just guessing.

Comment: Please post the execution plan using  `set showplan_text on;` and then running your query.